# tokenize in xpath using java code

Tags: java, xpath

is there any way to get tokenize value from xpath.

trying this but did't help.
String Xpath="tokenize(/root/child, '~')[1]";

getAttributeValue(element,Xpath);

```
public static String getAttributeValue(Element obj, String xpath) throws Exception{


XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpatha = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpatha.compile(xpath);
String value =(String) expr.evaluate(obj, XPathConstants.STRING);


return value;
```

}

```
<root>
<child>hello~How~Are~You</child></root>
```

I need 'How' Second token from xpath. how i can get this

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use an XPath 2.0 or 3.0 or XQuery 1.0 or later implementation (as `tokenize` was introduced in 2007 in XPath 2.0 or XQuery 1.0) and a suitable API that allows you to return the values that XPath 2.0 or XQuery 1.0 deal with.

So for instance using Saxon 9.6 and XPath 2.0 I would suggest to use http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/xpath-api/s9api-xpath.html.

Comment: I am passing xpath from external path and I position of the token is dynamic.. so I am looking a way  from just passing string xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Given you're working in Java it may be simpler to do the "tokenize" there rather than in the XPath:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpatha.compile("/root/child");
String value = ((String) expr.evaluate(obj, XPathConstants.STRING))
  .split("~")[1]; // Java counts from 0, XPath from 1
```